# Getting number of hits from Google API

Tags: api, search

I've tried to find a way to do this, but without success. I'm looking for a way to find out how many hits a search gets, and I don't want to do this manually, or with regex searching trough the html code. Surely the Google APIs must have a simple way to do this.

Does anyone know of one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [Google AJAX Search API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html)

Specifically `estimatedResultCount`, from [here](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxsearch/documentation/reference.html#_class_GSearch)

Comment: Unfortunately the Google AJAX Search API seems to be deprecated since 2010. It suggests Custom Search API, but it doesn't seem to be quite the same. Anyone who has another option?