# Algorithm or tips how to measure celebrity popularity across the world programatically?

Tags: php, algorithm, automation, artificial-intelligence, data-mining

Here is the situation :

Let's say I want to check who is more popular among five celebrities, and display the three most popular.

Let's say these five names are: "brad pitt", "will smith", "bruce willis", "enrique iglesias", "eminem" and I want to check who is more popular today.

(Very similar to Google's very famous page-rank algorithm.)

Is there any algorithms avilable for this task? If not, then please let me know how we can implement this.

Comment: Thanx paresh , for redifining my question

Comment: I think this question is too large in scope for SO's format. There are a couple of things here which you need to define. First off, where are you getting your data from? Your algorithm would be used to evaluate your data, not to gather the data itself. You need to define your sources to build up this data first.

Comment: @JohnP: we can use google, wikipedia, IMDB such popular sites to get information about this celebrities. but how to evaluate this data now.. what after we get information ? how we can evuluate this that is the question ?

Comment: You have to define popularity.

Comment: Any of the Ranking algorithms are worked only based on particular statistical data available. Based on the data we can create ranking algorithm. First you need to search for the data.

Comment: @JohnP : this is what i'm asking. according to you what should be the criteria to measure popularity. (Example : lets say i can compare number of movies they had done in first step)

Comment: @Ben : we can not store this much data. we need to analyse data that are already available on internet. Do you know any algorithm that can perform this task ?

Comment: @PareshBalar Like I said in my earlier comment, this question is overly broad. How do you define popularity? How do you compare a movie celebrity to a music celebrity to a sports celebrity? How do you compare quantity and quality? Before you do any of this, you need to build yourself a normalized data set.

Comment: There are startups that are trying to solve this problem. You might want to go and look at Klout as a starting point.

Comment: @JohnP : i know what are you saying. but this is my problem also. lets say we can define number of fans as one parameter for this !!

Comment: @JohnP : hey thanks for Klout. this will be helpful for me to continue my work and research. thanks again. if you have more info about this you can share.

Comment: Ranking of a celebrity is based on some of the following factors:
1. Area wise Popularity
2. Quality
3. Awards and nominations
4. Social and Charitable works. 
So you need to collect the data from the available resources and also make an online survey, then analyse the data and finally create an algorithm with the help of any available ranking algorithms.

Comment: @Ben : thanks for the information. hope i can use all this informations. do you know which are the best ranking algorithms that i should study ?

Comment: You Can Follow Reddit ranking algorithm first.
Links are:
1. Pyhton - http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588 
2. PHP - https://gist.github.com/1478806

Answer (score 2):

Just do a google search of each actor's name in quotes and see how many results google estimates there to be.

At the time of writing, searching for
'"Brad Pitt"' gave 'About 91,000,000 results (0.27 seconds)'
and
'"Will Smith"' gave 'About 61,200,000 results (0.31 seconds)'
so I would consider Brad Pitt to be the more famous of the two.

I am sure this can be done programmatically using some API and I am guessing its fairly agnostic to your choice of search engine i.e. Brad is probably more popular on Bing as well!

Comment: i think google doesnt give number of result using api , might have to parse page..

Comment: @sandeep: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2546858/getting-number-of-hits-from-google-api

Answer (score 1):

You Can Follow Reddit ranking algorithm first.
Links are:

1. Python - http://amix.dk/blog/post/19588
2. PHP - https://gist.github.com/1478806